# No such file or directory exists PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm trying to run the following code, but when i run the last chunk it errors out by saying there's no such file or directory found.

The error occurs in the last chunk!

Not sure what to try since I'm not great with Python

```py
def get_prices(share_symbol, start_date, end_date, 
    cache_filename='stock_prices.npy'):
    try:
        stock_prices = np.load(cache_filename)
    except IOError:
        share = Share(share_symbol)
        stock_hist = share.get_historical(start_date, end_date)
        stock_prices = [stock_price['Open'] for stock_price in stock_hist]
        np.save(cache_filename, stock_prices)

    return stock_prices.astype(float)


def plot_prices(prices):
    plt.title('Opening stock prices')
    plt.xlabel('day')
    plt.ylabel('price ($)')
    plt.plot (prices)
    plt.savefig('prices.png')
    plt.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    prices = get_prices('MSFT', '1992-07-22', '2016-07-22')
    plot_prices(prices)
```

> FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in get_prices(share_symbol, start_date, end_date, cache_filename)
>         4     try:
>   ----> 5         stock_prices = np.load(cache_filename)
>         6     except IOError:
>
> C:\Users\MRX\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py in load(file, mmap_mode, allow_pickle, fix_imports, encoding)
>       369     if isinstance(file, basestring):
>   --> 370         fid = open(file, "rb")
>       371         own_fid = True
>
> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stock_prices.npy'

Comment: Do you have a file called `stock_prices.npy` in the folder where you are running this code?

Comment: Instead of just sharing the error, providing the entire error output is more helpful, as it literally says where the error occurred. However, the obvious answer appears to be: there's no such file or directory. Don't you mean 'stock_prices.py' (note no `n`)

Comment: I'm just running it in Jupyter, not sure where stock_prices.npy is going. The entire error output is huge but I can post it.

Comment: You haven't answered @rdas or my question yet though, is the file called `stock_prices.npy` in the folder where you are running this script? If it is in some other location, you need to provide a correct path to the file.

Comment: `np.load(cache_filename)` is expecting the file `stock_prices.npy` in the same directory where the notebook is there. So, copy the `stock_prices.npy` to your notebook directory and run again. Alternatively, provide the full path to the `stock_prices.npy` file in `cache_filename` parameter and run.

Comment: I have no idea what or where this folder is? How do i find that out?

Comment: Got it to work. Turns out the library i was using (yahoo_finance) no longer has a working API. Needed to pip installed yfinance for it to work.